# Avoiding Y-scrollbar at height: 100vh; resp. h-screen;

Tags: css, scrollbar, tailwind-css

I want to align an element horizontally and vertically and have problem with the y-scrollbar.

It's about a success page. Simple structure: navbar, main, footer. And I use TailwindCss. In the main I would center an icon with the words Thank You! vertically and horizontally. Which I can also do with flex.

```
<div>
  <h2 class="text-3xl text-center my-10 ">some text</h2>
  <div class="flex h-screen justify-center items-center bg-gray-500">
    <div class="text-center text-green-500 text-3xl">
      <svg class="w-40 h-40" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
      THANK YOU!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center my-10">beautiful footer</div>
</div>
```

Here the Link to the example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/gWnstjwGur

### My Question

However, I have the problem here that now the Y-scrollbar is visible. Which I don't want. It is clearly due to h-screen. How can I implement this without the Y-scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a single full-page that has no scrolling, use `overflow-y: hidden;` on your wrapper. This way you can't scroll vertically at all.

If you still want to be able scroll but just not have a scrollbar:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.remove-scrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE + Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div class="remove-scrollbar">
  <h2 class="text-3xl text-center my-10 ">some text</h2>
  <div class="flex h-screen justify-center items-center bg-gray-500">
    <div class="text-center text-green-500 text-3xl">
      <svg class="w-40 h-40" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
      THANK YOU!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center my-10">beautiful footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this is not the answer to my question. I also see no change

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then. Do you want your icon centered? As for my solution, it might not work because tailwind has preset rules. You can overwrite them with `!important` if needed. Working example: https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/XWajJaa

Comment: the icon is already centered. Take a look: `https://play.tailwindcss.com/gWnstjwGur` my problem is only the 100vh resp. h-screen in talwindcss. navbar + 100vh; + footer = y-overflow of navbar height and footer height. how reduce the main section with 100vh that the scrollbar is no showing

Answer (score 0):

you should give the h-screen class to the root div and also give flex class, then the header and the footer will be fixed height, but the center div should fill the remaining height, which means adding flex-1 class to the center div.

Final state:

```
<div class="h-screen flex flex-col">
  <h2 class="text-3xl text-center my-10 ">some text</h2>
  <div class="flex-1 flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-500">
    <div class="text-center text-green-500 text-3xl">
      <svg class="w-40 h-40" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
  THANK YOU!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center my-10">beautiful footer</div>
</div>
```

[You can also check from playground link here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/aMsA6Hntlu)